# Is there a module or functionality to export/import roles and permissions?

Tags: 7, users, importing-exporting

I have been searching for a module or functionality to export/import roles and permission from one installation to another, but could not find it. Is there such a functionality or module for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module.

Comment: I did before asking this question, but I can't find any operational menu to do this (module is enabled).

Comment: Features can be created at the Drupal path `admin/structure/features/create`.

Comment: Ok got it. Once created, the feature can be exported and installed like a module on the target site. Thanks.

Comment: JVerstry  You can find more information about Features in the Drupal Tag wikis at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/features/info